# iframe scrolling position

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I have an iframe with a like button from facebook and it's a bit small i want to scroll the iframe from the left for 15px;

Here is my code:

```
<iframe id='likebutton' frameBorder='0' allowTransparency='true' src='http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href="www.facebook.com/makestream"&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=53&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80' style='position:absolute;width:26px;height:23px;overflow:hidden;border:0;'></iframe>
```

is there anyway to do this with javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can change CSS with code like this:

```
document.getElementById("likebutton").style.marginLeft="15px";
```

or with jQuery:

```
$("#likebutton").css("margin-left","15px");
```

Comment: Ok sorry i didnt understand your question here is a code for scrolling an iframe:
var myIframe = document.getElementById('likebutton');
myIframe.onload = function () {
    myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord);
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for scrolling in iframe:

```
document.getElementById('likebutton'); 
myIframe.onload = function () { 
myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord); 
}
```

Live example:
http://jsbin.com/ipujo/1/edit

Comment: thank you for that i did search in google and sow that example but it doesn not work with facebook like button